# Locked ERC20 paid out as tx-fees to DAO holders

Tags: solidity, erc-20, gas-limit, dao

I'm creating a contract where people transact by using locked `ERC20` tokens.

For example - you'd have 500 of token `A` locked in the `DAO` contract.

You decide to send 100 of token `A` to some other account. The transaction fee was set to 2% of the transaction value. So 98 tokens went to the account you sent them to and 2 tokens need to be paid out to `DAO` holders in proportion to their holding.

Since I'm not allowed to iterate over accounts because of the *gas limit* - is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I think I understand what you're saying... Give a few more details though. You are trying to enact a transaction fee on an ERC20 token that is paid out to other ERC20 token holders?

Comment: Yes - but thats not the hard part. The hard part is storing it and giving to all `DAO` holders without iterating and hitting the gas limit

Answer (score 0):

First, understand that if you just "burnt" the tx fee, it would do something similar, by decreasing the total supply, and making everyone's tokens proportionally more valuable. This is probably the easiest way to do it.

Second, yes, you definitely do not want to iterate though each address for every transfer. It would make a simple transfer very expensive (let alone possibly failing because of the gas limit). I would look at modifying an approach like this: [ERC20 Token and effective way to store dividends](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10864/erc20-token-and-effective-way-to-store-dividends?rq=1) if you really need capability so that DAO holders token count increases over time (if you don't want to go with the tx-fee burning process).